# bound, but not listening process

Tags: linux, tcp

python code for simple daemon

```py
import socket
import time
import signal

s=socket.socket()
s.bind(('127.0.1.1', 20201))

def stop(*a, **k):
    global work
    work = False

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, stop)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, stop)

work = True

while work:
    print('working')
    time.sleep(1)

s.close()
```

It's bound to port 20201, so i can be sure that only one instance is running.
If i try to run another instance, i see error, just as planned:

```
Address already in use
```

But i can't find a way to locate pid or any other info abount bound port

`netstat -a | grep 20201` gives nothig

`lsof -i TCP | grep 20201` gives nothing

`ss | grep 20201` gives nothing

Is there any way to find process for bound, but not listening port?

Comment: Perhaps `fuser 20201/tcp` ?  Don't you need to specify a protocol family when doing `socket()`? (I'm not so familiar with python.)

Comment: Doublecheck that 20201 isn't in /etc/services since netstat/lsof/ss may be using the port's name, not number.

Comment: Or use `netstat -an` so the port numbers will be numeric.

Comment: @wurtel Python presumably provides reasonable defaults for all the socket parameters.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this using `netstat -an`, so it does seem like this is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried `lsof -p <pid of python process>`. It includes the line:

```
python  1834 barmar    3u  sock    0,6       0t0 70994705 can't identify protocol
```

So while you can't find the process that has a specific port bound this way, you could use

```
lsof | grep "can't identify protocol"
```

to find all processes that have ports bound but not connected or listening. If there are multiple, you can probably figure out which is likely to be using the port you care about.

Note that there are other ways a socket can get into this state. When I ran the above command, it listed a long-idle `mysql` process. This is because `mysqld` closes idle client connections after a timeout. `mysql` detects this when it tries to send a new query, and reconnects at that time. But until then, the client process still has the old socket open, but there's no TCP connection associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that your IP:port combination is held by a *client* socket, sometimes it happens due to bad luck (the local port for a client socket is the randomly-generated "ephemeral port"). To check established TCP connections (-l limits to listening sockets) :

```
ss -tnp |grep :20201
```

Otherwise apply the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option between your socket creation and binding, a listening IP:port is not necessarily immediately available for reuse after your process termination (again because of any existing client sockets which were connected to your existing IP:port source, but in TIME_WAIT state).